# Why IP address detect by google and IP address on dlink device status are differ?

Tags: networking, portforwarding

I was trying to do port forwarding in my router. I have found weird thing. When i typed "my ip" on google it shows a IP address (figure 1) and when i gone through the router's device status information it shows a different IP address.
[image: figure1]
[image: figure2]

Why this happens in my desktop? i am using DIR-600M router.

Please help me friends?

Comment: You are asking a non-programming question on a programming site. You should ask your question on the correct SE site ([su]), but search it for CGN, first. There are  already questions and answers for this there.

Comment: will you please mention that questions and answers?

Comment: Just search if for `CGN`. There are a lot on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP may be using Carrier grade NAT for providing IP addresses to their clients. So ip address observed on google is not your public address but it is address of device used for NAT by your ISP. Then the IP on your router settings is the address provided by the device executing the NAT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely certain that you are not using a proxy, this should ideally be a question for your ISP.

You may want to check if you are being assigned with a real public IP or not; technically, some service providers do not necessarily provide a public IP that is actually exposed to public domain. They may assign you an IP through their DHCP servers that looks like a public IP, but it is not... This is similar to being behind a proxy where your actual IP is not exposed to outside.

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: How do i know my computer run a proxy server or not?

Comment: It's not that your computer runs a proxy, have you ever happen to change the DNS IP address to anything that is not assigned by the ISP? If no, then you probably are not routing through a proxy. You did not mention the ISP and the country. I know for a fact that certain non-US ISPs do not provide a public IP by default/ free; they would want you to pay for getting one.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when your router is connected to one more intermediate device (service provider's device). Both your router as well as the provider device will have a WAN interface. But, only the provider's WAN interface would be exposed to the public. That's the reason you will be able to see only providers WAN interface IP as the public IP.

If you want incoming traffic, you would need to setup port forwarding on both the devices.